# Where might I find a weird hybrid USB A-MicroB plug?

Tags: usb, connector, components, usb-c

I have a product with a USB-A plug that can open to reveal a Micro-B plug:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any idea how or where to find such a thing?  I tried searching Mouser and Digi-Key but don't see anything like it. (Actually, I would like to find a USB-A/Type-C hybrid, if such a thing is even possible mechanically, to avoid including illegal C-to-A adapters with products.)

Comment: If it's for a product and you can order a few thousand of them you might want to simply contact the brand that made that cable.  A digikey rep might be able to help too.  I've had them help looking stuff up even for my small orders.  They clearly aren't common though.  Where did you find the original?

Comment: The original is part of a cheap Amazon otoscope

Comment: This is a questions about *how to find something*, not seeking recommendations for specific products

Comment: @endolith Note to self: next time I want to ask about a part I cannot find, put it as "what part number is this?" and tag `identification` :)

Answer (score 3):

Not a flip but a slide [noname combo USB connector](https://www.elecrow.com/2-in-1-micro-usb-combo-usb-a-connector.html):
[image]
The [SilverStone CPU02 cable](https://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=628&area=en) with a flip combo USB connector:
[image]

One OEM for these kinds of plug is [Rego](http://www.rego.com.tw/product_detail.php?prdt_id=200) (thanks to @endolith for finding that).

Comment: How did you find these??  I really want one with an A plug and C plug, but I don't know if that is possible mechanically.  It might short out VBUS to GND

Comment: Found a manufacturer: http://www.rego.com.tw/product_detail.php?prdt_id=200